# Enqueue scripts inside a class

Tags: theme-development

I have written a small class that will handle enqueues in my theme :

```
<?php

class Header {

    public function init_hooks()
    {
        add_action('wp_print_scripts', array(__CLASS__,'include_all_files'));
    }

    public function include_css_files()
    {
        wp_register_script('style.css', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url'));
        wp_enqueue_script('style.css');
    }

    public function include_js_files()
    {
        wp_register_script('jquery-min', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-min');        
    }

    public function include_all_files()
    {
        $this->include_css_files();
        $this->include_js_files();
    }

}

?>
```

I call it right before closing the head tag, like :

```
$header = new Header();
$header->init_hooks();
```

But it does not work. There is no error, but no script is added. Any ideas ?

Comment: You're code is running after scripts have been output(you said just before the closing `<head>` tag, that's too late for the enqueues. The code needs to run before `wp_head()` does..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you call your class right before closing HTML tag? It is too late to enqueue scripts then.

Don't hook into `wp_print_scripts` to enqueue your scripts and styles. I just [learned](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/where-is-the-right-place-to-register-enqueue-scripts-styles/) this today from Rarst.

So change your init_hooks function to something like following:

```
public function init_hooks()
{
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array(__CLASS__,'include_all_files'));
}
```

Also you are using `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` functions to enqueue your styles, Wordpress has separate functions to enqueue your styles `wp_register_style` and `wp_enqueue_style`. Your `include_css_files` should look like:

```
public function include_css_files()
{
    // NOTE: you don't really have to use the filename as style slug.
    wp_register_style('my_style', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url'));
    wp_enqueue_style('my_style');
}
```

Now about instantiating your class and calling init_hooks. You can either place it directly inside your functions.php, or you can use the init action to instantiate your class.

Comment: just a small side question. I can't get the style to print without having something like "wp_print_scripts('style.css');" explicitly. Is this normal ? It does not like normal to me :/

Comment: Oops.. sorry I missed you are using wp_register_script and wp_enqueue_script to register and enqueue your styles. There are separate functions for styles, wp_register_style and wp_enqueue_style. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer as per the new things I learned today from Rarst. Checkout http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/where-is-the-right-place-to-register-enqueue-scripts-styles/

Comment: oh ok thanx i checked it, nice :)