# Where is the right place to register/enqueue scripts & styles

Tags: hooks, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-style, wp-register-script

I am using WordPress 3.1.4 by now. I am confused with where (which hook) do I use:

- to register and/or enqueue
- scripts and styles
- on front- and back-ends?

Questions:

- Which are right hooks to use?
- All front end register/enqueue scripts/styles in `init`?
- Why is there no `admin_print_styles-{xxx}`?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

### Why registering and queuing properly matters

- it should be **in time** - earlier than script/style is up for being output to page, otherwise it is too late;
- it should be **conditional** - otherwise you are loading stuff where you don't need it and cause performance and functionality issues, for this you need WP environment loaded to late stage.

### The three stages of the process

1. **register** - this explains WP details about script/style and makes it store that info;
2. **enqueue** - (often lumped together with register in one `wp_enqueue_*()` call) - this tells WP to add scripts/style to the queue, according to its settings (dependencies, header/footer loading).
3. **print** - this happens when WP processes queue, tries to load something specific for itself **or** when you explicitly do it with `wp_print_*()` function.

### Front-end structure of functions and hooks

- `wp_head()`

  - `wp_head`

    - *(1)* `wp_enqueue_scripts()`

      `wp_enqueue_scripts` **« this is what you need**
    - *(8)* `wp_print_styles()`
    - *(9)* `wp_print_head_scripts()`
- `wp_footer()`

  - `wp_footer`

    - *(10)* `wp_print_footer_scripts()`

It goes much deeper, but this is simple and good enough for important points:

- **`wp_enqueue_scripts` is most appropriate hook for registering and queuing scripts and styles on front end** and it is there specifically for that;
- `init` has nothing to do with this, it will work, but - **past Codex recommendation to use only it was incorrect**;
- you can get away with queuing scripts (not styles) for footer at any point before `wp_print_footer_scripts()` call;
- **`wp_print_*` hooks are NOT appropriate for register/queue**, they are points in code when output is already happening. They are appropriate for manual/custom script/style output.

### What about admin?

Well, the functionality there is even more complex, elaborate and nested.

- for starters **just use `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook** (it gets passed **`$hook_suffix` global for conditional stuff**) for everything, it will do nicely for most cases;
- when you need something complex - look through `admin-header.php` and dig from there for appropriate hooks.

### What about login?

There's a specific hook named `login_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: Hmm in another answer to [another question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20479/why-are-admin-scripts-not-printed/20487#20487), I was recommended `admin_print_scripts-{xxx}`. I found that `admin_print_scripts` was called but not with `-{xxx}` eg. `-edit.php` for example. How right is that answer of enqueuing in `admin_print_scripts-xxx` and what will you recommend instead - suppose I want to include scripts/styles in a custom post type add/edit page (for metabox)

Comment: @JM at Work as above my personal opinion - stay away from `*print*` hooks unless you really know why you need them. And overall they are for **print**, not **queue**. `admin_enqueue_scripts` hooks passes `$hook_suffix` variable that is same as used in those dynamic hooks.

Comment: `$hook_suffix` looks like post.php in my edit portfolio page why is that? I thought it was edit.php also, how do I then determine if I am editing/posting a portfolio & not a normal post?

Comment: @JM at Works honestly that variable is somewhat nasty :) In own plugin it's easier to deal with it (return of `add_*_page()` function), but in native WP screens it can be different things.

Comment: Unfortunately when I change the hook from wp_footer to wp_enqueue_scripts or admin_print_scripts the CSS dissapears and doesn't show up anywhere in the source code.  This is the code I use: add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addCSS');  That DOES NOT work, this DOES work add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addCSS');  except for it obviously adds the CSS to the footer.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Talon I don't think it should even be possible to add CSS to the footer?.. Also your examples looks same and without seeing code itself I find it hard to guess what is going on.

Comment: This is an old topic but what exactly does `wp_print_styles` and such do exactly? [The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_styles) doesn't explain what it does but states not to use it.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee do you mean as in hooks or as in functions? As function they are essentially doing actual output of scripts/style to page and those function have hooks inside respectively.