# wp_enqueue_style in Plugin

Tags: plugins, css, wp-enqueue-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the right place to register/enqueue scripts & styles](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/where-is-the-right-place-to-register-enqueue-scripts-styles)

When I enqueue a css style in a plugin like so:

```
function add_my_stylesheet() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myCSS', plugins_url( '/css/myCSS.css', __FILE__ ) );
}

add_action('init', 'add_my_stylesheet');
```

Is 'init' the correct action to use? It works fine. Is there any reason not to do it this way? Is this the standard way? I want to follow the best practices.

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: Do you want to enqueue style on plugin's options page?

Comment: if you only have 1 wp_enqueue_style, just add it directly in your plugin, no need to add any function or add_action.

Comment: @Sean Lee bad advice. It is **strongly** recommended to enqueue only inside appropriate hooks. It is also commonly recommended to not run any code during plugin load, other than hooking function/methods for executing code later.

Comment: Agree with you Rarst in general, especially when there are multiple of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `admin_print_styles` for your hook, this is the preferred method for adding a style to your plugin or admin page.

```
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'add_my_stylesheet');
```

Comment: Why `WP_PLUGIN_URL` and not `plugins_url()`? EDIT: Just reading here (http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories) that the contants are intended for core use, not plugins.

Comment: You're right, not just for SSL but if the plugin is not in the default plugins directory, removing it.