# wp_enqueue_style for Plugin with multiple stylesheets

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I'm making a navigation plugin which adds animations to your wordpress navigation.

I read in Wordpress Codex that I would need to use wp_enqueue_style().

First, How do I use this code for multiple css files?
in my main plugin file.

Now according to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27604/wp-enqueue-style-in-plugin?newreg=6d888d1ce82543d9bce2129afb2f2375) question, I would add stylesheets like this:

```
function add_my_stylesheet() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myCSS', plugins_url( '/css/myCSS.css', __FILE__ ) );
}

add_action('admin_print_styles', 'add_my_stylesheet');
```

Since my plugin requires multiple stylesheets to be added, which of the two codes should I use?

```
function add_my_stylesheet() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myCSS', plugins_url( '/css/myCSS.css', __FILE__ ) );
}

add_action('admin_print_styles', 'add_my_stylesheet');

function add_my_stylesheet1() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myCSS1', plugins_url( '/css/myCSS1.css', __FILE__ ) );
}

add_action('admin_print_styles', 'add_my_stylesheet1');
```

Or

```
function add_my_stylesheet1() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myCSS1', plugins_url( '/css/myCSS.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myCSS1', plugins_url( '/css/myCSS1.css', __FILE__ ) );
}

add_action('admin_print_styles', 'add_my_stylesheet1');
```

Now I know where to add this code. But how do I call the stylesheet I want to use?

Also, just to clear what my plug would do:
The main plugin file would only load the stylesheet required.
And the options page would allow the user to select which of the stylesheet to require.

for example, in php format I would use the following:

```
<link href="nav-<?php echo $name; ?>.css">
```

The $name should be the one selected from the options page, but how do I call in the required stylesheet?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your first question, you would use the second style, i.e.

```
function add_my_stylesheet() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myCSS', plugins_url( '/css/myCSS.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myCSS1', plugins_url( '/css/myCSS1.css', __FILE__ ) );
}

add_action('admin_print_styles', 'add_my_stylesheet');
```

What the [`add_action()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) does is tell WordPress, "When [the `admin_print_styles` action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_styles) occurs, run this `add_my_stylesheet()` function." Confusingly, [the practice of using the `admin_print_styles` and `admin_enqueue_styles` actions to enqueue stylesheets is **incorrect**](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/) - as counter-intuitive as it is, you should use [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) instead.

The calls to [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) then add the specified stylesheets to a list of stylesheets that will be loaded (if you specify the dependencies argument, then WordPress will also take care of making sure that your stylesheets load in the correct order). You don't need to "call" an enqueued stylesheet as you suggested - if it is enqueued, then it **will** be printed out in an HTML `<link ...>` element in the `<head></head>` section in the same manner that WordPress loads it's own stylesheets.

In order to select which stylesheet will be loaded, you simply add your logic to your `add_my_stylesheet()` function; if you don't wish for a stylesheet to be used, then you don't enqueue it, i.e.:

```
function admincolorplugin_enqueue_styles() 
{
    // Get the user's stylesheet choice from the options, default to "white"
    $stylesheet = get_option( 'admincolorplugin_stylesheet', 'white' );

    // Conditionally load the appropriate stylesheet
    if( $stylesheet == 'black' ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'admincolorplugin-black', plugins_url( '/css/black.css', __FILE__ ) );
    }
    else {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'admincolorplugin-white', plugins_url( '/css/white.css', __FILE__ ) );
    }
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admincolorplugin_enqueue_styles' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an if to check if it conforms to your criteria, for example

1. a specific page/post (id)
2. all pages/post
3. related to the admin option.

That way it'll only pull the CSS that you want on the desired page / when the desired admin option is selected.

```
    function add_my_stylesheet1() 
    {
        if(is_page(41)){
            wp_enqueue_style( 'myCSS1', plugins_url( '/css/myCSS.css', __FILE__ ) );
        }else{
            wp_enqueue_style( 'myCSS1', plugins_url( '/css/myCSS1.css', __FILE__ ) );
        }
    }
```

Or:

```
    function add_my_stylesheet1() 
    {
        $adminopt = get_option( $option, $default );
        if($adminopt == "Normal CSS"){
            wp_enqueue_style( 'myCSS', plugins_url( '/css/myCSS.css', __FILE__ ) );
        }else{
            wp_enqueue_style( 'myCSS1', plugins_url( '/css/myCSS1.css', __FILE__ ) );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'safely_add_stylesheet_to_admin' );

/** * Add stylesheet to the page*/
function safely_add_stylesheet_to_admin() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-style', plugins_url('plugin_styles.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-basic', plugins_url('/css/basic.css', __FILE__) );

}
```

Comment: Please, **always** explain what code does. Just file an [edit] and explain **why** your code solves the OPs problem.