# Where to enqueue stylesheets for plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script

I want to enqueue stylesheet to plugin I'm developing, like this:

```
function utm_user_scripts() {
    $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style',  $plugin_url . "/css/style.css");
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'utm_user_scripts' );
```

I am adding this code in the main file, [plugin_name].php.

Nothing is loaded, which part am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this code in your main file: [plugin-name].php:

```
    function utm_user_scripts() {
            $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'style',  $plugin_url . "/css/style.css");
    }

    add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'utm_user_scripts' );
```

So basically, you need to use 'admin_print_styles'. At least it did the trick for me.

Comment: The right way to enqueue the styles should be with add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_func'). Maybe the issue was with an older version of WP because wp_enqueue_scripts is working now with enqueing plugin styles

Comment: The action 'wp_enqueue_scripts' enqueue scripts on the front end, the action 'admin_print_styles' enqueue scripts on the wordPress backend

Answer (score 3):

I did a quick [Google Search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wp%20enqueue%20style%20plugins%20url) on how to enqueue styles for Plugins and I've came across these two questions on WordPress StackExchange. You can find them below and hopefully they will help you solve your problem.

Best of Luck :)

[wp_enqueue_style for Plugin with multiple stylesheets](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136655/wp-enqueue-style-for-plugin-with-multiple-stylesheets)

[Where is the right place to register/enqueue scripts & styles](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/where-is-the-right-place-to-register-enqueue-scripts-styles)

Comment: I have seen these and did as instructed, but it's still not included.

Comment: Then we need more information on the matter - are you getting errors in the console? Try some debugging and then post what you get and I'd be happy to help even more :)

Comment: The correct answer according to WP is to hook admin scripts and styles to the "admin_enqueue_scripts" action. Which is very well explained in the 2nd link in this answer.