# Include my files in a plugin?

Tags: plugins, html, paths

I have problem with including my files into a plugin, mycontactform folder and files within it works fine in localhost and I can do CROD methods but, I don't know how to share my files into plugin.

```php
<?php
/*
*Plugin Name: Contact Form
*Plugin URl" https://www.jeti.com
*Description: A plugin for contact form and application form
*Version:1.0
*Author: Jetmir Zela
*Author URl: https://www.jeti.com
*License:GPL2

*/
add_action('contact', 'contactform_example_function');

function contactform_example_function(){
include('home.php');
}

add_shortcode('contact', 'contactform_example_function');
?>
```

Comment: Please can you pick one version of the question, e.g. this one, and edit as much information into it as you can and close the others? That's four questions now.

Comment: You have a contact form that works outside WordPress but now you want it to work from WordPress; you've got a simple plugin that includes the main page of the form as above, but the styles don't work. How are you including the styles in home.php? Is it a full HTML page, i.e. it has its own style links in the header, or is it an HTML snippet with just the form? You probably want to make the file you include just the form, and use wp_enqueue_style to include any new CSS, making sure you [get the path right](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/218452/3276).

Comment: Please do not ask the same question more than once. Fix the original insted.

Comment: You also don't know how to make the form work. I guess you're posting to a PHP file that's now inside your plugin? You probably want some other more WordPress-like mechanism to accept the post, or you need to specify the full path in the post action the same as you would the CSS files above.