# JavaScript enque stopped working

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, footer

Somewhere along the line I have messed up my  js enqueue I am not sure how. I have the following in my functions.php file and I am including `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` in my footer.php before the js files were outputting in the footer no problem, but now it isn't working and I don't know why?

```
function foundationScripts() {
    if (!is_admin()) {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js', false, '1.7.1',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

  wp_enqueue_script('modernizr.js',get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/modernizr.foundation.js',false,false,true); // for some reason this adds extra quotation marks in the body
  wp_enqueue_script('foundation.js',get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/foundation.js',false,false,true);
  wp_enqueue_script('app.js',get_template_directory_uri() . '/javascripts/appF.js',false,false,true);
  }    

add_action('init', 'foundationScripts');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if you posted code as-is or extracted part of it, but per this snippet - you are hooking function **inside itself**. Which doesn't seem like it will work nicely. :)

Also `init` hook should **not** be used for enqueue, on front-end hook to use is `wp_enqueue_scripts`, see [where is the right place to register/enqueue scripts & styles](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/where-is-the-right-place-to-register-enqueue-scripts-styles).

Example `functions.php` code (assuming `foundation` is prefix you are using?):

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'foundation_after_setup_theme' );

function foundation_after_setup_theme() {

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foundation_wp_enqueue_scripts' );
}

function foundation_wp_enqueue_scripts() {

    // enqueues go here
}
```

Comment: +1 for noticing `wp_enqueue_scripts` missing.

Comment: This is the code posted as. How should I modify the functions code exactly. Do I just get rid if init and add wp_enqueue_scripts to my footer.

Comment: @Anders Kitson You should change to and move `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foundationScripts');` line outside of this function (and even better practice is dedicated initialization routine, hooked to `after_setup_theme`).

Comment: @Rarst sorry I don't know what you mean by hooked to after_setup_theme. What I did was delete the function and placed wp_enqueu_scripts in my footer.php file and it works now, is that the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

`add_action` needs to be outside the original function.  Right now, it's in the function outside the `if (!is_admin())` function.

Edit: As Rarst pointed out, you also need to use `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of `init`.