# Jquery Theme Roller to Wordpress

Tags: themes, jquery

How can you load a custom made Roller Theme for Jquery ui to wordpress?

I recently created and downloaded a new theme for the datepicker, but can't get it loaded.

I tried adding the css file to my theme files then doing an 'enqueue style' function, but seem to be missing something.

```
function my_add_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style('datepicker', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/js/datepicker.css');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing is to hook the functions, that register/enqueue your styles and scripts, at the right "time".

This would be on the `admin_*/wp_*/login_enqueue_scripts`-hooks.

<sup>Read about the instruction on WPDevel.</sup>

This answer [provides even more details about the process of registering scripts & styles](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/where-is-the-right-place-to-register-enqueue-scripts-styles).

If you want to check if your script/style passed certain points inside `WP_Dependencies`, then  simply use the following functions:

```
// is registered?
wp_script_is( $handle );
wp_style_is( $handle );
// is enqueued?
wp_script_is( $handle, 'queue' );
wp_style_is( $handle, 'queue' );
```

Comment: Oh, my mistake forgot the other line of code `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_add_styles');` I tried admin_ and login_ too, but no dice

Comment: What's odd is I put the css file in the same place as Flexslider.css and enqueued the sheet in the same place in the functions.php file. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean run something like this - `function is_enqueued_script( $script )
{
    return isset( $GLOBALS['wp_styles']->queue[ $script ] );
}
print (int) is_enqueued_script( 'datepicker' );` ? That returned a 0

Comment: Okay, apparently everything being overridden by a plugin (sigh). Thanks for your help kaiser, much appreciated

Comment: See update (and please, clean up the comments - thanks).