# Which action to hook wp_enqueue_script to? wp_head or wp_enqueue_scripts?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, codex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the right place to register/enqueue scripts & styles](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/where-is-the-right-place-to-register-enqueue-scripts-styles)

According to [`wp_enqueue_script()` documentation in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), it seems that one should hook `wp_enqueue_script()` calls to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action instead of `wp_head`. That contradicts all the tutorials I have ever read on the subject, which suggests adding to `wp_head`.

Which is the right way to do it?

Thanks in Advance :0

Comment: You are reading some poor tutorials. :) Switch the sites you follow.

Answer (score 5):

I took a long time figure out the right way for this! Here's what I follow now:

*Use case*: **In a plugin's admin page**

*Hook*: admin_print_scripts-<page hook> OR <the php file name for your plugin>

```
$hook = add_menu_page(...) / add_submenu_page(...);
add_action('admin_print_scripts-'.$hook, 'my_callback');
```

*Use case*: **On all admin pages**

*Hook*: admin_print_scripts

```
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'my_callback');
```

*Use case*: **On all front end pages**

*Hook*: wp_enqueue_scripts

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_callback');
```

And the callback:

```
function my_callback(){
    wp_enqueue_script(....);
}
```

Note: Use the same for enqueueing styles too (wp_enqueue_style)!

**Edit:** I checked the codex for `admin_print_scripts`, they now suggest to use `admin_enqueue_scripts` instead. I ran a search through version 3.4.1 core files, and found they use `admin_print_scripts-<hook>` internally! So you can use it too!

It works flawlessly!

Comment: `*print*` hooks are semantically for script output, not enqueue. It's not set in stone but I prefer and recommend to stick with `*enqueue*` hooks to enqueue for consistency.