# How to use wp_enqueue_script, style when required

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

There are lot of unused js & stylesheets in my theme.

here is wp_register function in my functions.php

```
wp_register_script( 'moder',    base_url . 'js/modtom.js', array(), false, false );
wp_register_script( 'videojs',  base_url . 'js/vin.js',    array(), false, false );
wp_register_script( 'selevizr', base_url . 'js/sesin.js',  array('jquery'), false, true );
wp_register_script( 'easi',     base_url . 'js/gmin.js',  array('jquery'), false, true );

wp_register_style( 'styles',     base_url . 'style.css', null, false );
```

i want these scripts to be run when required or when shortcode use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the right place to register/enqueue scripts & styles](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/where-is-the-right-place-to-register-enqueue-scripts-styles)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a shortcode:

```
function load_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('moder');
  wp_enqueue_style('styles');
}

add_shortcode('load_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

Then use the shortcode to enqueue the scripts/styles:

```
[load_scripts]
```

Or so:

```
do_shortcode('[load_scripts]');
```

In terms of running when required, you have to make sure that if you're loading something that requires these, that you either execute the shortcode or enqueue those scripts/styles, since WordPress won't automatically know when you need them.

As a side note, wrap the function either in a class or give it a unique name to avoid collisions.

Resources:

[Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

[do_shortcode function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)

Comment: +1, but note it only works for 3.3+