# Using Underscore Templates in WordPress

Tags: jquery, media-modal, underscore, backbone

I've noticed that since WP 3.5 that we now have the Backbone.js and Underscore.js libraries included.  The new Media Modal uses Underscore templates and I was wondering how would I be able to insert them, especially in the admin side of things.Is there a correct way to insert these?

Comment: Please search the site for [questions related to how to enqueue scripts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=enqueue+script).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the right place to register/enqueue scripts & styles](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/where-is-the-right-place-to-register-enqueue-scripts-styles)

Comment: @ChipBennett this question is not about register/enqueue scripts, it is about using underscore templates in new Media popup

Comment: Technically you're both right.  My fault for posting a question while half asleep.

Comment: Can you load an Underscore template from an external file via a script tag?

Comment: @ChipBennett I'm not asking how to enqueue underscore, I'm asking how to include the templates in the page.  The question you point to doesn't say anything about that, so I don't understand how this is a duplicate

Comment: What are Underscore "templates"? HTML markup? CSS? How are they used?

Comment: http://www.headspring.com/tim/an-underscore-templates-primer/.  WP is currently using them in their media models for their views. Basically, they are reusable snippets of HTML you can autopoulate with JSON data, like from an AJAX response.  WP has them wrapped in script tags near the end of the admin page and I wanted to know how how to get them there and @EugeneManuilov's answer put me in the direction I needed by using admin_footer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your plugin index file:

```
add_action( 'print_media_templates', 'wpse8170_admin_footer' );
function wpse8170_admin_footer() {

    require 'templates.php';
}
```

Your templates.php:

```
<script id="tmpl-mytemplate" type="text/html">
    <h1>Hello {{data.name}}!</h1>
</script>
```

Your media js file:

```
wp.media.view.MyView = wp.media.View.extend({
    template: wp.media.template('mytemplate'),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template({name: 'world'}));
    }
});
```

Comment: How do we trigger the view?