# Blip Slideshow plugin Mootools/jQuery conflict

Tags: jquery

This particular site uses the Blip Slideshow plug in (because it's fed by a Picasa web rss feed) and also a jQuery powered slider. The plug in inserts the Mootools script links ahead of the jQuery ones in the header which breaks the slider. I can push the Mootools links to the footer but then Blip doesn't work.
The script that calls the slider is already using jQuery no conflict - I think correctly:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.fp-slides').cycle({
    fx: 'fadeZoom',
    timeout: 8000,
    delay: 0,
    speed: 500,
    next: '.fp-next',
    prev: '.fp-prev',
    pager: '.fp-pager',
    continuous: 0,
    sync: 1,
    pause: 1,
    pauseOnPagerHover: 1,
    cleartype: true,
    cleartypeNoBg: true
});
 });
```

I've read many forum answers about how to use no conflict but don't know where else it may need to be applied to resolve this. 
The scripts in use are:
Mootools v1.3.1
jQuery v1.7.1
jquery.cycle.all
I can post links or any other code that might need to be seen if someone can help sort this out.

Comment: Hi Matt. Please read the part of the [faq] that tells about what's on- and what's off topic. Also please always link to the plugin code in question.

Comment: Hi Kaiser-This is a WP question so I thought it was on topic and didn't want to overload it with code. I'd normally link to the site but this is a production site so had to removethe offending bits.

Comment: I was talking about a link to the _Blip Sideshow_ Plugin. Please read my above comment again ... _sigh_.

Comment: can you tell me what are the possible values for "fx" please...!!!???

Answer (score 0):

There turned out to be 2 problems which made it a bit harder to fix.
I had to move the link to the jQuery plug in that runs the slideshow (cycle.all) so it was below the Mootools and jQuery library links.
And a plug in called Tabber Widgets had to be deactivated. 
Both were required to solve the issue.

Comment: Oh, mate. You should really read how to [load scripts & styles](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/21579/385) and how to assign dependenices (loading orders).