# JS script not being included

Tags: jquery

I am trying to enqueue a js file in functions.php but its not working. Following is my code

```
 add_action('init','shopswing');
function shopswing(){

    if(!is_admin()){
        wp_register_script('swing',get_stylsheet_directory_uri(). '/js/swing.js',array('jquery'));  
        wp_enqueue_script('swing');
    }
}
```

and somehow, my site stop responding when i include the code of swing.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("ul>li>img").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).parents("ul")
        .find(".toolTip")
        .animate({ 'height':'200px'})
        //.css({"display":"block"});
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $(this).parents("ul")
        .find(".toolTip")
        .animate({ 'height':'0'})
        //.css({"display":"none"});
    });
});
```

Comment: Read [Where is the right place to register/enqueue scripts & styles](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21561/where-is-the-right-place-to-register-enqueue-scripts-styles), and look at your browser’s console to find JavaScript debug information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem! The problem was with the name of function, i am using woocommerce and i think the function name conflicted, changed it and it working!

Comment: That’s not really an explanation.

Comment: you should use 'wp_enqueue_scripts' instead of 'init' to include js.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses the [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) version of jQuery which does not allow

```
$.
```

use

```
jQuery.
```

or simple replace

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function()
```

by

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ )
```

hope that helps.

Comment: I tried but nothing, is my enqueue thing fine? i see that when i removed the script of enqueue from functions.php, the website was running