# Echo outside HTML

Tags: html, scripts

I'm new to Wordpress and I want to echo a script and a css file inside the footer.php .
This is the code that I use.

```
echo "<script src='file.js'></script>";
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file.css">';
```

The problem is that the codes are appearing at the top of the document, although I place them in the bottom of the footer.php file.
Why is this happening?
[image: wordpress php outside the html]

Comment: You cannot add styles in the footer. `<link>` tags outside the `<head></head>` tags is invalid HTML

Comment: Make use of the system WordPress offers to enqueue scripts/styles, this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/21579/22534) gives you a good overview.

Comment: Also, use `wp_enqueue_scripts` to add styles and scripts